# How to fix image_url error in odoo website template

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I get this error

```
raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_url'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akoh/isodir/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 331, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_web_layout_1075
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_url'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_url'
Template: web.layout
Path: /t/html/t[2]
Node: <t t-set="x_icon" t-value="website.image_url(website, 'favicon')"/>
```

Anytime I add `<t t-call="portal.portal_layout">` to my template like this

````xml
<template id="mass_sale_order_portal_template" name="Mass Sales Order Portal Template">
        <t t-call="portal.portal_layout">
                    <!-- <div class="col-12 col-lg justify-content-end"> -->
                    <h2><span t-esc="test"/></h2>
                        <!-- modal relative to the actions sign and pay -->
                    <div role="dialog" class="modal fade" id="modalaccept">
              

                        <div class="modal-dialog" >
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <header class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Validate Order</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
                                </header>
                                <main class="modal-body" id="sign-dialog">
                                    <p>
                                        <span>By paying this proposal, I agree to the following terms:</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><span>Accepted on the behalf of:</span> <b t-field="sale_order.partner_id.commercial_partner_id"/></li>
                                            <li><span>For an amount of:</span> <b data-id="total_amount" t-field="sale_order.amount_total"/></li>
                                            <li t-if="sale_order.payment_term_id"><span>With payment terms:</span> <b t-field="sale_order.payment_term_id.note"/></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </p>
                                    <div t-if="pms or acquirers" id="payment_method" class="text-left">
                                        <h3 class="mb24">Pay with</h3>
                                        <t t-call="payment.payment_tokens_list">
                                            <t t-set="mode" t-value="'payment'"/>
                                            <t t-set="submit_txt">Pay &amp; Confirm</t>
                                            <t t-set="icon_class" t-value="'fa-lock'"/>
                                            <t t-set="form_action" t-value="sale_order.get_portal_url(suffix='/transaction/token')"/>
                                            <t t-set="prepare_tx_url" t-value="sale_order.get_portal_url(suffix='/transaction/')"/>
                                            <t t-set="access_token" t-value="sale_order.access_token"/>
                                        </t>
                                    </div>
                                </main>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- modal relative to the action reject -->
                    <div role="dialog" class="modal fade" id="modaldecline">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <form id="decline" method="POST" t-attf-action="/my/orders/#{sale_order.id}/decline?access_token=#{sale_order.access_token}" class="modal-content">
                                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                                <header class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Reject This Quotation</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
                                </header>
                                <main class="modal-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Tell us why you are refusing this quotation, this will help us improve our services.
                                    </p>
                                    <textarea rows="4" name="decline_message" required="" placeholder="Your feedback..." class="form-control" />
                                </main>
                                <footer class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" t-att-id="sale_order.id" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Reject</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </footer>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <!-- main content -->
                        <t t-foreach="orders" t-as="sale_order">
                        <div id="introduction" t-attf-class="pb-2 pt-3 #{'card-header bg-white' if report_type == 'html' else ''}">
                            <h2 class="my-0">
                                    <t t-esc="sale_order.type_name"/>
                                    <em t-esc="sale_order.name"/>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </t>
                   
        </t>
    </template>
    
Here is the controller rendering this template.
```python
@route(['/my/mass/orders/<int:order_id>'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def portal_mass_order_page(self, order_id, orders, report_type=None, access_token=None, message=False, download=False, **kw):
        try:
            order_sudo = self._document_check_access('sale.order', order_id, access_token=access_token)
        except (AccessError, MissingError):
            return request.redirect('/my')

        if report_type in ('html', 'pdf', 'text'):
            return self._show_report(model=order_sudo, report_type=report_type, report_ref='sale.action_report_saleorder', download=download)

        # use sudo to allow accessing/viewing orders for public user
        # only if he knows the private token
        # Log only once a day
        if order_sudo:
            # store the date as a string in the session to allow serialization
            now = fields.Date.today().isoformat()
            session_obj_date = request.session.get('view_quote_%s' % order_sudo.id)
            if session_obj_date != now and request.env.user.share and access_token:
                request.session['view_quote_%s' % order_sudo.id] = now
                body = _('Quotation viewed by customer %s', order_sudo.partner_id.name)
                _message_post_helper(
                    "sale.order",
                    order_sudo.id,
                    body,
                    token=order_sudo.access_token,
                    message_type="notification",
                    subtype_xmlid="mail.mt_note",
                    partner_ids=order_sudo.user_id.sudo().partner_id.ids,
                )

        values = self._order_get_page_view_values(order_sudo, access_token, **kw)
        values['message'] = message
        
        # values = {}
        values['orders'] = orders
        values['test'] = "testing"
        sum_total = sum([vals.amount_total for vals in orders])
        domain = expression.AND([
                ['&', ('state', 'in', ['enabled', 'test']), ('company_id', '=', order_sudo.company_id.id)],
                ['|', ('country_ids', '=', False), ('country_ids', 'in', [order_sudo.partner_id.country_id.id])]
            ])
        acquirers = request.env['payment.acquirer'].sudo().search(domain)

        values['acquirers'] = acquirers.filtered(lambda acq: (acq.payment_flow == 'form' and acq.view_template_id) or
                                                     (acq.payment_flow == 's2s' and acq.registration_view_template_id))
        values['pms'] = request.env['payment.token'].search([('partner_id', '=', order_sudo.partner_id.id)])
        values['acq_extra_fees'] = acquirers.get_acquirer_extra_fees(sum_total, order_sudo.currency_id, order_sudo.partner_id.country_id.id)

        _logger.info("Testing values: %s", values)

        return request.render('main_membership_dashboard.mass_sale_order_portal_template', values)
````

If I remove `<t t-call="portal.portal_layout">` then it works but without css styling, I really can't trace the error or understand whats going on

Comment: I'm facing the dame error in Odoo 14

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in the controller file that was rendering the template. I misspelled the keyword "website='True'". If it is not there then add the keyword, if it is then check that you wrote it properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33250296)